# How to find the point at which density plot starts curving in Python?

Tags: python, density-plot

I have a simple density plot which looks like this:

[Density Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ4OP.png)

I want to get the point at which the graph starts curving, i.e. it is no more parallel to X-axis and similarly the point for which graph flattens back again.

Thanks

Comment: Will signal always be without noise? If so, you can take first value above some threshold (eg. 0.1) and it will indicate rising edge and then take the last as the end of curve.

Comment: Implemented this. Thanks.